# How to build a daemon to encode video files on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, ffmpeg, celery, video-encoding

I am interested in running a daemon to go over user uploaded video files and encode them in an optimal format (and add some watermarks).

I was considering services such as Zencoder, Encoding.com, Amazon's encoding service but some lack overlaying capabilities and some are just too expensive for our (big) volumes.

I want to build a daemon that encodes videos that are located on S3 once users upload them.

The solution I thought of would be Python Heroku servers using Celery for a task queue to keep track of the encoded files and ffmpeg to do the actual work. However, I ran into troubles compiling ffmpeg for Heroku (with libass support, so the basic ffmpeg bins aren't enough).

What approach/technology stack would you consider for this mini-project?

Thanks!
Yuval

Comment: FFmpeg is sort of the category killer for this type of thing. You would do well to power through the problems you're having with FFmpeg. Start with asking SO about the problems you're having with building FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ffencoderd](http://ffencoderd.sourceforge.net), is a basic perl daemon using ffmpeg, it accepts encoding jobs through a soap interface or locally creating files in an xml format under a server's directory. It enables a multimedia repository through an http server.

Hope helps,

(By the way i am the dev, :P , but serious, just tried to help)